# A pill that "pauses" the worsening or healing of a condition

Tags: internal-consistency, medicine

It was **2050** when scientists discovered a pill that can temporarily "pause" the change of a condition. After taking it **orally**, the condition of the patient stays unchanged for some time. Their situation doesn't worsen nor does it gets better on its own. It provides more time for emergency situations, providing 5 more minutes on average for doctors to react for some life threatening situations and sometimes an hour in less severe cases.

The pill is quite expensive to produce (about 10000 2022's US dollars per pill), therefore limited tests have been done, espencially when taking it continuously. However, some celebrities have been taking it for several years **everyday** in hope of being young and healthy forever. So far, the public has seen **no change** of their appearance nor their health.

There have been recorded incidents of children stealing these pills. Some confess they want their grandparents with **Alzheimer's** to remember their names **a day longer**. Some say they don't want to **grow up**.

Unfortunately, as every good technology did, this pill has been heavily abused. Due to its **relatively taste/odorless** nature, it can be served to targets who are already wounded as a mean to continue their suffering without their notice by spraying the **powder** into spicy foods. Fatally wounded targets just suffer for longer before they die. Targets with painful but nonfatal wounds are often kept in their wounded state indefinitely by being served with this type of food everyday. It is **very hard to prove** this pill was used by measures like blood tests, urines after the target is released, so it has been wildly abused by countless organizations, underground or not.

---

Question: Is the pill satisfying the above properties (especially the bold parts) possible to develop within the specified timeframe? (i.e: Are similar efforts already underway?)

You are free to give the pill to the person using other means in life threatening cases, but it has to work orally for other cases.

You are free to give the pill a limit as to how long it can extend lifespan but it has to be more than 200 years.

Edit: Magic is not allowed.

Edit 2:

1. For making the fatally wounded live longer, providing blood externally is allowed.
2. Organizations using this pill to keep targets in a wounded state are smart enough to not administer it in the final days of keeping the target, so you can assume it has enough time to disappear. As long as it doesn't change the body permanently, it is fine.
3. It doesn't prevent infection, burns, or anything like that. It would slow down infections but do nothing if the patient is contacting fire. Even worse, it slows down healing sometimes to a halt in nonfatal cases of burning.

If this is still too magical, limiting it to physical wounds and aging (which doesn't need to be completely stopped, see above) is okay, too. I'll just have to write the story around that limitation.

The reason why I required this to be available in 2050 is to make sure we have a society that is similar to the society we have now, in order to demonstrate the socioeconomical effect. If there is a way of demonstrating the similarity of the society to our society, the time requirement can be void.

Comment: If I was a chemist working on such thing I would not say it to a random stranger on the internet. What is your actual worldbuilding problem?

Comment: `possible to develop within the specified timeframe` - i'd say a pill like this is _completely impossible_ without using magic.

Comment: @L.Dutch Just, want to **reality-check** this so people reading it would think this is actually possible in 2050.

Comment: A pill which works both as a sort of emergency haemostatic (in order to allow "fatally wounded targets just suffer for longer before they die") and as a method of mitigating memory loss due to Alzheimer's? Not likely at all.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Why tho? Is there a requirement I can take away to make it possible? Thanks for reminding me to edit my question to exclude magic.

Comment: The troublesome requirement is for the pill to be effective against *everything*. That's not how medical drugs work.

Comment: @AlexP Can you give more reasons as to why these two can't be done as the same time? If I don't require mitigation of Alzheimer's, would it be much more realistic?

Comment: for starters, you can't stop _natural healing_ since it's the exact same biological process of _keeping the body alive_ - the cells are _constantly_ dying and being regenerated. next: a pill that prevents someone from bleeding out (cause of death in "fatal wounds") is _logically_ impossible - except maybe for magically increasing blood generation to a level high enough to compensate the blood loss (ignoring the required liquid and energy input). and a pill that treats "every condition" is just pure handwavium in the first place. life itself is a constant condition of "decay and regeneration".

Comment: @AlexP What about just physical wounds and aging? Is that much better?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann What about slowing the process down? Only a delay in death is required in those fatal situations.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sorry I misread your comment. For the nonfatal situations, could it be done so that the speed of regenerations slows down so that the body have no extra for healing?

Comment: It may work as a prop in a story. Or it may not work. Depends on the kind of story, on how the story is told, and so on. It probably wouldn't be believable if the story is supposed to be very realistic. It probably would be perfectly acceptable in a story full of other fantastic elements. Some stories are intended to be reflections of real life; many stories are not.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Blood would be provided externally in fatal situations.

Comment: @AlexP I do intend to make this story a reflection of real life as in the social interactions and the socioeconomical problems. I'm not sure how that would work in a fantasical setting. I believe any society too different from ours would be problematic. I am willing to sacrifice some properties of it, as you can see in my comments.

Comment: Another issue is the undetectability. We can only assume that it's identical to something already present in the body - and nothing in the body approaches doing what you're asking. It's an instance of [unobtanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium), nothing wrong with that , but trying to explain the actual science behind something that's non-real is rather an opportunity for humour and conceit in the writing than technical brilliance.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Undetectability isn't required when the target is in captive. The capturers are smart enough to not use this pill in the last days of capturing the target, so you can assume it has enough time to disappear. As long as it doesn't make permanent changes to the body on its own, it's fine.

Comment: The title of the question says "a condition", but the body of the question implies that it prevents all healing, all worsening, all infection, even senescence. Presumably it also magically stops other kinds of cellular damage accruing too, like burns. If I take it, would I become fireproof? Does it prevent hypoxic damage? Does that make me undrownable, too? Can I get a volcano hottub?

Comment: @StarfishPrime It merely slows down the natural process of aging and effectively stops healing in some circumstances. For fire damage, the pill would not do anything when fire is actively contacted (you would still be getting a burn as serious), and it would slow down healing.

Comment: While this pill doesn't sound possible to me, your scenario and the society you are describing sound compelling. I would be willing to suspend my belief a little for the sake of reading this story. That said, what sounds most implausible is the idea that a pill would both prevent aging and healing processes. Life is not static and the body is constantly making new cells. If it stopped healing itself and making new cells, it seems like aging would quickly occur. And vice versa: no aging seems like it would mean fast healing.

Answer (score 3):

**Nanobots administered via pill**

These nanobots go through a process that may take some time to get to work, but do amazing things once its operating correctly. The concept is this is administered to a healthy person to ensure continued health.

Upon first dose, the nanobots check for the presence on the core structure, if not present, they are programmed to create it. The core structure is a small AI core that is capable of intelligent learning. This structure is built in some area of the body which wont cause much of a disturbance to the rest of the body. All nanobots are programmed to follow the instructions of and feed information to the core structure.

Next, the AI will begin to map the body and establish the "status quo" it is required to maintain. Initially, this will take a good amount of time, but as the nanobot population increases (due to additional doses) and the AI learns, the mapping progress rapidly increases.

The AI and nanobots continuously map the body, looking for changes. Unfortunately, due to this being a first gen technology, the AI is pretty dumb. It does not care if a cancer cell should be there or not. If it was there during the initial mapping and not during subsequent mapping, (maybe due to the body eliminating it) the nanobots would then construct the missing cancer cell. The nanobots use materials in-situ to "repair" damages it notes.

Due to the nanobots being very advanced machines, made of materials not found in the human body, they need to be replaced constantly (daily doses.) otherwise, due to wear and tear and natural biological elimination, they need to be replaced constantly.

Now, due to technological issues, it cannot really do much in the lines of DNA and gene editing, thus cant really assist with the aging process. basically, these nanobots can assist in the repair (or damage) cells, but really cannot create them.

Comment: I feel like an issue of the AI being dumb is going to be solved pretty quickly, given the usefulness of the pill. "some celebrities have been taking it for several years"

Comment: Dumb is a relative term compared to human intelligence. Present technology, AI is pretty dumb if you matched it up to a human in a game of wits. However, we do have AIs doing pretty amazing things within the scope of their programming, such as Googles search algorithms. In the future, this will change, but will be a long and slow process to get their. These scientists probably want to cash in on their tech within their life time so they put out a product, expecting to patch the AI as time goes on to improve it

Comment: Wait, does this mean the person cannot preserve new memories over time?

Comment: hmmm.... that may be true. If you form a new neuro connection in the brain, the AI may see that as an anomoly. horrible side effects.

Answer (score 2):

## It isn't possible because injuries have enormously different causes.

When you are stabbed, you die of bloodloss. The pill would need to stop you bleeding, and stop you regenerating blood, and stop a number of organs from dying of lack of oxygen.

Alzheimers is caused by misfolded proteins in the brain causing damage. Stopping bleeding and blood regeneration and a lack of oxygen causing damage to organs isn't gonna do anything.

Aging is caused by damage from sugar, telomere shortening, and oxidative damage.

Humans don't have a static health thing that you can pause. That's the domain of magic.

A universal healing pill that could prevent all injuries would be an enormous scientific achievement, and isn't realistically gonna be achieved in 30 years. It's even harder since you want it to be undetectable, so it can't simply be some mass genetically engineered bacteria that floods your blood stream.

No single sneaky molecule is gonna do all that.

## To make it work, have it be good bacteria.

You could package a lot of life saving stuff into a genetically engineered bacteria. Fast clotting? Sure, bacteria can form matts across wounds. Some genetic treatments to boost lifespan? Quite possible.

Presumably rather than replicating it uses some rare elements that aren't present in the body, so you need regular new doses.

But it can't be undetectable. Bacteria are easy to see with a microscope, and it's easy to separate blood to find other parasites like viruses. Undetectable things don't cure everything.

The bacteria eat and consume normal clotting factors and other healing chemicals, supplanting the body's normal healing systems.

Comment: The undetectability requirement is quite loose. As long as the pill does not make permanent changes, it should be fine. You can see my edit of the question. Also, since a lot people have complained (I really didn't know it would be this difficult), I have given alternative ways to satisfy some requirements. Hopefully this would be more realistic. The problem with "good bacteria", is that it doesn't prevent healing. Not sure what could be done to deal with that.

Comment: I added how it suppresses healing. They disable it, presumably so they can do their work more effectively.

Comment: Problem with using some rare elements that aren't present in the body is that those elements would leave traces. That counts as "permanently altering the body".

Comment: Nanobots or bacteria also leave traces, even if they die. That's an inherent risk with complex lifeforms. Alive or dead, they produce all sorts of detritus which is easily detected with a quick immune swab.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it doesn't? What about an antidote that can elimate all traces, administered just before release of the target?

Comment: You are inserting some complex machine, bacteria or nanobot, into every tissue of the body and changing every aspect in a radical way, and you also want it to eliminate all traces, with only 30 years of tech improvement?

If you want to make it more realistic, how about you have it be some alien tech? They find a crashed ship, they find this tech on board, and it has whatever criteria you want from thousands of years of technical development.

Answer (score 0):

It can't exist, life is a process not a state.

The only way to halt aging and all forms of injury is stop stop all chemical reactions, which is instantly fatal because a living human is nothing but trillions of competing chemical reactions, Many of which need to keep running to fight entropy. It is like asking if you can freeze a tornado in place and still have it be a tornado when you unfreeze it, freezing it has stopped the conditions that let it keep existing.

Many forms of injury are made worse by some normal reactions running without other ones, thats why you have to stop all of them.  Even using super advanced magic-esc nanotechnology you would need a colony of nanomachines that understand all that chemistry, monitors it in real time, and can alter it in real-time, which is beyond the computing power of the species right now.

Comment: Even with these alternate requirements in the edits, it still can't be real?

Comment: No, with sufficient technology (like 100year out or more) you might have a tank you could dunk them in full of nanites but that would not just pause it it would fix wounds. the problem is the "any injury or condition" part, that requires tech so advanced it can manipulate the body at the atomic level, but if it can do that it can rebuild the body at the atomic level too.